# Particle System scattering in the entire scene when parented in object with path animation

Tags: animation, particles, parent, path

I've parented the particle emitter to the UFO, so far its good it follows the object with path animation. But unfortunately there are few particles that is scattering from the entire scene. Also when I play the animation the parented object sometimes glitches. It moves from the path animation to a different area for a split second. (This only happens when I parent the particle emitter to the object.)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to bake to see what it gives?

Comment: Yes sir. I tried to bake it but its pretty the same.

Comment: @CharlieTan Particle system has a lot of cache "glitches" ... so try increase +/- 1 number of particles and bake ... if that doesn't help, share simplified blend via https://blend-exchange.com ... delete all that doesn't participate on the issue (or attach objects needed to reproduce issue into a new file.